# How to Create a MySQL Table with more than 4096 Columns?

Tags: mysql, excel

You can find,

> "MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective
>   maximum may be less for a given table. The exact column limit depends
>   on several factors:"

in [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html).

Today I got a MS Excel Sheet with nearly 25,000 columns. I need to convert it to MySQL. I know how to convert it using PHP.

But problem is the limitation of MySQL. Is there any solution to overcome it?

Comment: Excel column limit is 16,384 so I'd be interested to see how that file was created...

Comment: @TimWilliams It is in multiple sheets, but I need them for one MySQL table because otherwise it is hard to run queries, Even Excel is useless because those are in multiple sheets.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: @Strawberry   more like wrong tool for the job...  I work for a company infamous for pulling crap like this in excel.  When they just don't have a solid grasp on when to use spread sheets vs DB.

Comment: I am morbidly curious... I want to see this spread sheet, to wrap my mind around this many columns and why.  Is this a file u would be willing to share?

Comment: @DarbyM I am sorry I can't share it because my client will not give permission for it. It is really really bad design. It is not needed those columns.  99.99%+ columns are something like Boolean. I mean values of those fields just Yes or No.  If I get those details to MySQL I can make better design. Then using PHP I can create good design Excel sheet which has very less columns. That's why I wanted to get it for MySQL. Basically what I going to do is Excel convert to MySQL, Then MySQL convert to Better MySQL design. Again it convert to Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, MY GOD 25k column excel sheet.. how many days that take to open? Lol.

My approach would be build a UID colum in the spread sheet.   Then spit the spread sheet into 25 different sheets, all containing ~1000 of the columns... also properly inserting the new UID column into each new split sheet.   Then import each sheet into its own table.   At this point u have something at least usable in MySql......

To clarify the purpose of populating the UID to every sheet is for the ability to join the tables back together as needed in MySQL.

Side Note:  25k columns I can't help but think someone used excel for what excel is not meant for.  :)